# Is there an easy way to change the format of a datetime input field of a Django form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-template-filters

I understand that in a built-in Django filter called [`date`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#date).

I want to modify the date format of a `DateTimeInput`, but I can't figure it out without actually manually writing out the entire HTML. So currently I do something like this:

```
<input id="{{ field.id_for_label }}" type="text" name="{{ field.name }}" value="{{ field.value|date:"F j, Y, g:i a" }}"
    class="round datetimepicker {% if field.errors %}error-input{% endif %}"
/>
```

Notice how I use `value="{{ field.value|date:"F j, Y, g:i a" }}"` (those double quotes actually work).

Is there an easier way to do this? Preferably I would like to keep it the same format as my other input fields:

```
{{ field|add_class:"round datetimepicker"|add_error_class:"error-input" }}
```

where `add_class` and `add_error_class` is from [Django widget tweaks app](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the docs. 
the [DateTimeInput widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#datetimeinput)
takes one optional argument as the format of its initial value.
Hope that helps

Comment: Plus check [the DateTimeField form field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.DateTimeField.input_formats) also

Comment: Nice ok. I don't know how I missed that. Thanks! I guess I was so used to the custom filter widget that I forgot to check how to do the original method of adding options via `views.py` and `forms.py`.